# Where are Outline VPS's logs file stored in Windows11?

Tags: windows, vpn

I recently switched my home PC to Windows11 and in my old Windows10 I used to work with [Outline](https://getoutline.org/) VPN. I created a new access key using the OutlineManager app from the very same Windows11 PC, but when I try to connect to the server using the OutlineClient app I can't get connected and the app doesn't give me any reason.

For testing purposes I used the same access key in my Android phone and the phone connects without no problem at all.

I would like to know where are **OutlineClient**'s logs stored in Windows11 in order to troubleshoot the connectivity issue. I tried to look up in `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\` and `C:\ProgramData\` but got not logs file.

Any light in matter will helps.

PS: I'm using the latest OutlineClient's version.